# How does one restore data to phone from Google drive?

Tags: restore, google-drive, google-backup

I backup my data from my Android phone to Google Drive. I then performed a full factory reset. I was given the option to exchange data with another phone, but not restore from Google Drive.

When I go to Google Drive from the app, I'm able to see the backup. I can view the files, but the only option I'm given is to delete them.

Is there something I'm missing? Why can't you restore incrementally from Google Drive? And how do I get my data back without having to do another factory restore? Finally, why wasn't I given that option when I perform the factory restore?

Comment: That's one of the reasons this type of backup is what I discourage from (it's not a backup if I cannot chose when and what to restore – but I'm preaching the choir here I guess). If you don't mind the command line (`adb shell`), you *might* be able to trigger things via `bmgr` (the "backup manager"). I've never played with it so I cannot give detailed instructions, hence just this comment as pointer. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup) for more – and please let us know the outcome!

Comment: It doesn't appear that this will work with the existing backup. So is what I have on Google Drive useless?

Comment: No idea; I've stopped using Google stuff years ago, my devices run LineageOS w/o GApps.

Comment: you could maybe download to pc and analyze file format, maybe it can unpacked and restored manually

Answer (score 0):

Here's a real-life case on someone who'd gotten Google Backup to restore indirectly without root: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1STY4aX9oDW-U55MeoB4D4AMWbvFiS2-u/view?usp=drivesdk)

As I recall, a manual trigger for the G Backup restore function was planned for the Pixel series, but this was over a year ago that I'd read about that so I'm not sure what became of that; at that time, an ADB command existed to trigger such behavior, but I'm unsure what the prerequisites and/or limitations are.

My post [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207965/adb-backup-and-restore-app-data-between-device-and-emulator) also briefly touches on G Backup and other methods I'd explored to solve my own issue with restoring a backup file's data.  Note that there is versioning requirement for the standard restoration method(s) to work, i.e., you can only restore onto a device running the same or higher  of Android (if even then).

Finally, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_OJmTAspJDxn2HPe69hZimowt7zlBq0_/view?usp=drivesdk) is a guide I wrote (and [fixes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fnFExwEAP7tQK7ou_ZxTayTJg8lts-iS/view?usp=drivesdkb)) for an Android game, but the same functionality can be applied to more general usages as well.